# Convert SSD MobileNetV2 custom model to edgetpu model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-coral, mobilenet, edge-tpu

I'm trying to convert the mobilenetv2(ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8 ) model to EdgeTPU model for object detection. And ı'm using TF2.

I tried many solution but still have "cpu operations" when i convert tflite model to edge tpu. how can i convert whole mobilenet model?

Here my steps;

1. Download pretrained model(mobilenetv2), prepate dataset(spesific class from coco) and train your model.
2. Export checkpoints ./exporter_main_v2.py and now i have "saved_model.pb , assest, checkpoints" under saved_models files.
3. Turn step2, install tf-nightly 2.5.0.dev20210218  and "export_tflite_graph_tf2.py" and export model now.
4. This step, trying to quantize model for edgetpu(8bits) and converting to .tflite files. Scripts like these ;

```
  def representative_dataset_gen():
    for data in raw_test_data.take(10):
      image = data['image'].numpy()
      image = tf.image.resize(image, (320, 320))
      image = image[np.newaxis,:,:,:]
      image = image - 127.5
      image = image * 0.007843
      yield [image]
  
  raw_test_data, info = tfds.load(name="coco/2017", with_info=True, split="test", data_dir="/TFDS", download=False)

  converter =  tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('~/saved_model')
  converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
  converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
  converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
  converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
  converter.allow_custom_ops = True
  converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
  tflite_model = converter.convert()
  
  with open('{}/model_full_integer_quant.tflite'.format('/saved_model'), 'wb') as w:

  w.write(tflite_model)
```

5. After quantization visualize from netron and model properties like these ;
   [image]
6. And i convert .tflite model to edgetpu model with "edgetpu_compiler" and my final models ;
   [image: have 7 CPU operations]
   [image]

Comment: Currently, the EdgeTPU compiler cannot partition the model more than once, so as soon as an unsupported operation occurs, that operation and everything after it executes on the CPU, even if supported operations occur later. As mentioned at https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#model-requirements, the EdgeTPU requires 8-bit quantized input tensors. However, if you pass the Edge TPU Compiler a model that's internally quantized but still uses float inputs, the compiler leaves a quantize op at the beginning of your graph (which runs on the CPU). Likewise, the output is dequantized at the end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still cant get it. Where is my wrong steps? I hope quantized to all my model. how can i recover to cpu operators? @Manoj

Comment: Can't comment without seeing the TPU tflite model but are you using TensorFlow Live V3?